# How to calculate the ranking of multiple items by choosing 2 by 2

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, optimization, ranking

Let's say I have an array with songs. I'd like to make a program that gives the user 2 songs and they deciede which one is their favorite. It repeats that, until the program can give a ranking of all the songs from the users favorite to least favorite.

I tried to make it like this: give each song 0 points, check if any songs have the same amount of songs and ask which one of the two is the users favorite. Repeat that until all songs have a different amount of points. Sadly the algorithm is way too slow and asks about the same two songs multiple times.

Comment: Is this for homework, or for real use? If it's for real use, are you sure users will have the patience for this? Even if you fix the bug and stop asking about the same pair more than once, the number of combinations still becomes large very quickly as the number of songs goes up. For example, if you want to rank 100 songs, that's 100C2 pairs, which is 4,950 pairs. Most users are not going to have the patience to go through that many iterations of the "A or B?" question.

Comment: Isn't it just sorting?

Comment: No, @user58697, the OP is trying to interactively *determine* the value of each item, not sort pre-valued items.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it's for real use and a way to learn to code in java. Mostly as a hobby. I know the pairs would go up quickly, but I would use the program mostly for songs in an album, so basically only 20 elements would have to be sorted. Plus, we don't have to try every combination. If I say that song A is better than B and B is better than C, there is no need to compare A and C.

Answer (score 0):

```
let a = ["Christmas", "Halloween", "Thanksgiving", "NY"];
a.sort((a, b) => confirm(`${a} is yes, ${b} is no`) ? -1 : 1);
```

That's some JS, for example. @user58697 was right, it's just a sorting problem because you're creating an order based on two inputs. An equivalent algorithm would be trivial in Java, but depends on whether you're working with JavaFX, Swing, or AWT.